# ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1

Tags: terminal, laragon

I started the terminal from Laragon and now show this message:

Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.

Current directory:
C:\laragon\www

Command to be executed:
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C Multimedia\Stage\Architoi\Test Vue\test" cmd /k "C:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5..\init.bat"

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...

I don't know what happens, I appreciate a solution for return to normal.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the console path, the same thing happened to me. It was solved with this path:

```
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat
```

This is shown in the image where the console path is added.

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry about the late of my answer but thanks :), finally I changed to use VSC and his terminal